# How to use Kryo with RMI

Tags: java, serialization, rmi, kryo

I see a lot of questions about *if* Kryo can be used to replace default JVM serialization that RMI uses, but nothing in the way of *how* to actually set it up. I've heard that Kryo is a "drop-in" replacement for JVM serialization, and not sure if that just means you can swap out some JARs from the runtime classpath (as is the case with SLF4J bindings, etc.), or something else.

So I ask: how do I get RMI using Kryo instead of the default JVM serialization that Java ships with? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kryo is not a drop-in replacement for Java Object Serialization: it is a new API; and RMI cannot be made to use it.

Comment: Thanks @EJP (+1) - is this different than JBoss Serialization (which I also heard was a drop-in replacement)? If so, why and how can RMI use JBoss Serialization, but not Kryo? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding why, given 2 jars that do the same thing (Kryo and JBoss Serialization), one can be used with RMI, and the other can't.

Comment: Because Kryo isn't a drop-in replacement, as I said. Have a look at the API and see for yourself. I doubt that JBoss Serialization is drop-in either frankly, but I'm open to correction.